Why is my Docker container persisting data?
I'm deploying several microservices to local Kubernetes (enabled in Docker Desktop) using Tilt. Tilt basically automatically deploys the services to Kubernetes given a manifest yaml file.
One of the services is a Firebase emulator. The problem is that when I kill the deployments and then later deploy them again, after a few seconds after the Firebase emulator is up, Firestore fills up with previous data.
I don't want it to persist any data.
If I delete all data in Firestore and run tilt down (delete deployments) and tilt up (deploy services to Kubernetes), the same issue happens again. Database is loaded with the same data after a short delay.
I want to understand why this is happening.

Here is the Dockerfile for starting the Firebase emulators:
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk11
RUN npm install -g firebase-tools

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000 4400 4500 8085 8086 8087 9000

ENV GCP_PROJECT=my-project
ENV ENABLE_UI=true
ENV UI_EMULATOR_PORT=4000
ENV HUB_EMULATOR_PORT=4400
ENV LOGGING_EMULATOR_PORT=4500
ENV PUBSUB_EMULATOR_PORT=8085
ENV FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_PORT=8086
ENV STORAGE_EMULATOR_PORT=8087
ENV HOSTING_EMULATOR_PORT=9000
ENV SINGLE_PROJECT_MODE=true

# Prevent Firebase from attempting to use the GCP metadata server for authentication
ENV NO_AUTH=true
ENV GCE_METADATA_HOST=""

ENTRYPOINT ["firebase", "emulators:start", "--project", "my-project"]

According to the docs, Tilt runs a standard docker build.
If I run kubectl get deploy firebase-emulators -o yaml to get its yaml file, I get this:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"firebase-emulators","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"tilt"},"name":"firebase-emulators","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"firebase-emulators"}},"strategy":{},"template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"firebase-emulators","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"tilt","tilt.dev/pod-template-hash":"f23d48fe3d7b64dfd5de"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"firebase-emulators-image:tilt-40e89bb0022ca2c3","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"firebase-emulators","resources":{},"startupProbe":{"failureThreshold":12,"httpGet":{"host":"host.docker.internal","path":"/","port":4000},"initialDelaySeconds":3,"periodSeconds":5,"successThreshold":1,"timeoutSeconds":1}}]}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-08-06T21:05:15Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: firebase-emulators
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: tilt
  name: firebase-emulators
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "95758"
  uid: 75db218c-aea3-4c18-bcb5-634372d3a79b
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: firebase-emulators
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: firebase-emulators
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: tilt
        tilt.dev/pod-template-hash: f23d48fe3d7b64dfd5de
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: firebase-emulators-image:tilt-40e89bb0022ca2c3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: firebase-emulators
        resources: {}
        startupProbe:
          failureThreshold: 12
          httpGet:
            host: host.docker.internal
            path: /
            port: 4000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2024-08-06T21:05:40Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2024-08-06T21:05:40Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2024-08-06T21:05:15Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2024-08-06T21:05:40Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "firebase-emulators-7fbcf868cb" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1

This is my firebase.json:
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 8086
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 8087
  },
  "emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 8086
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 8085
    },
    "storage": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 8087
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 4000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hub": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 4400
    },
    "logging": {
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 4500
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}

And .firebaserc:
{}



Initially I thought it was Kubernetes persisting data, I ran kubectl delete pvc --all && kubectl delete pv --all to delete persisting volumes, but nothing was found.

I noticed in the logs Tilt is probably reusing images [event: pod firebase-emulators-7fbcf868cb-5cblw] Container image “firebase-emulators-image:tilt-40e89bb0022ca2c3” already present on machine. Is database associated with image reuse? Manually deleting the images in Docker Desktop didn't work.

I was also advised to add --export-on-exit=/tmp/empty to the ENTRYPOINT in Firebase emulators Dockerfile, but this also did not work.

I tried deleting all volumes before deploying the services, same result. When I run tilt up I see one volume related to Tilt being created, and that's it.



I'm going to guess this is specific to Tilt.  Your Dockerfile doesn't have a VOLUME declaration and your Deployment spec doesn't reference volumes at all, so unless Tilt is trying to hot-patch and restart your existing container, I don't know what would persist data either.  (...I learned yesterday that Tilt parses Dockerfiles, so I'm not going to be too surprised...)

The Firebase Emulator suite doesn't persist anything at all between executions unless you're using the --import and --export-on-exit flags.  See the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#startup. Are you sure your code is actually using the emulator, and not the actual hosted Firebase services?  You haven't showed that code, we can't tell.

Yes, the code is calling the emulators in localhost. I noticed old data are being loaded when inspecting localhost:4000/firestore/default, the Firebase UI. And this happens after a few seconds, initially it's empty, and then it loads the same old data.
About the containers David mentioned, as I see they are all deleted in Docker Desktop before I run tilt up

There shouldn't be anything in Firestore at all when the emulator starts, unless you are using --import.  If you are seeing things, then there must be some bug (or you have some other process populating it), and you should report your steps to reproduce the issue on firebase-tools.

Ok, this is embarassing... ‍♂️ Turns out one of the other dozens of services was running some code to populate initial data. No issue with Tilt nor Kubernetes. Thanks for the help!
